# conjugacy class preserving deformation of symmetric group

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, deformation-theory

It is a well-known fact in a group representation theory that all elements of the same conjugacy class possess the same trace (character) in any representation of a group. I deal specifically with symmetric groups $S_n$, which are generated by basic generators $\sigma_{i,i+1}$ with $i=1...n-1$. Two elements of the symmetric group belong to the same conjugacy class if they represent permutations with the same cyclic structure. My question is the following: can one take some representation of the symmetric group (with $\sigma_{i,i+1}$ mapped to matrices $T_{i,i+1}$) and deform it (probably sacrificing the group structure) in such a way  (basic generators $\sigma_{i,i+1}$ are mapped now to some matrices $\tilde{T}_{i,i+1}$) that traces of products of some *prescribed* amount of generators still depend only on the cyclic structure of the corresponding permutation?

One obvious example is to take matrices $T_{i,i+1}$ of any representation of $S_n$ and to multiply them by a number. If $\sigma_{i,i+1}$ is mapped to $\alpha T_{i,i+1}$ then trace of product of $m$ matrices will be equal to $\alpha ^m$ times a character of $S_n$ and will depend only on the cyclic structure of generators. A less trivial example is to take permutation matrices and to add to each matrix element the same constant: $(\tilde{T}_{i,i+1})_{pq}=(T_{i,i+1})_{pq}+a$, where $(T_{i,i+1})_{pq}$  are matrix elements of permutation matrices.

I wonder if there are more examples of such a behavior and if there is an underlying theory that allows one to construct such deformations.

Comment: In principle, would you be happy to see a deformation such that, somehow, group elements of length 2 have "characters" dependent only on their cycle structure, but there are elements of length 3 with the same cycle structure but different "characters"? For both of your examples, it seems that any $m$ will work. (I have no idea how to answer this question either way, but I think this is a good candidate for MathOverflow.)

Comment: As long as I consider a product of some prescribed amount of generators, I don't worry about characters of elements obtained in a different way. If the same cycle structure appears in a product of a different amount of generators then it is of no importance for me

Comment: Actually I understand now that if I take a reducible representation of $S_n$ and multiply block matrices that correspond to different irreps by different factors then I will be able to obtain linear combinations of irreducible characters. My second example is exactly such a case because permutation matrices give a reducible representation. But still the question remains: are there any other deformations?

Comment: So I think the answer to the question in my comment is "No." I think that your condition is: For any $m$, let $a_i$ each be some generators $\sigma_{j,j+1}$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$, and similarly for $b_i$; if $a_1\cdots a_m$ has the same cycle structure as $b_1\cdots b_m$, then we demand $\text{tr}(\overline{T}_{a_1}\cdots \overline{T}_{a_m})=\text{tr}(\overline{T}_{b_1}\cdots \overline{T}_{b_m})$. Is this correct? (I've abused the notation slightly but hopefully it is understandable: by $T_{a_i}$ for instance I mean $T_{j,j+1}$ for the corresponding $j$.)

Comment: (The question in my comment was asking "Do you want 'for any $m$' or only 'for a fixed $m$'?" e.g. in the latter case, the class of all such deformations would depend on $m$, while the former case is the intersection of all those classes.)

Comment: Yes, this is the question. A weaker version is to restrict to $m=n-1$